# Json serialization in MVC

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

Below are my two model classes

```
public class ResponseData
{
  public List<string> labels { get; set; }
  public List<string> series { get; set; }
  public List<dataForMetric>  data{ get; set; }        
}

public class dataForMetric
{
   public List<int> value { get; set; }
}
```

and my action method is

```
 public ActionResult GetData()
 { 
   ResponseData res = new ResponseData();
   res.labels = new List<string>() { "day1", "day2", "day3" , "day4"};
   res.series = new List<string>() { "dummy" };
   res.data = new List<dataForMetric>() { new dataForMetric() { value = new List<int>() {10} } ,
                                               new dataForMetric() { value = new List<int>() {110} } ,
                                               new dataForMetric() { value = new List<int>() {120} } ,
                                               new dataForMetric() { value = new List<int>() {130} } 
                                             };
        return  Json(res, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);           
    }
```

The JSON output of above action method is

> {"labels":["day1","day2","day3","day4"],"series":["dummy"],"data":[{"value":[10]},{"value":[110]},{"value":[120]},{"value":[130]}]}

But for my requirement the output should be

> {"labels":["day1","day2","day3","day4"],"series":["dummy"],"data":[[10],[110],[120],[130]]}

Please let me know how it can be achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dataForMetric class is unnecessary. You can achieve the desired result with a list of lists:

```
public class ResponseData
{
    public List<string> labels { get; set; }
    public List<string> series { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> data { get; set; }        
}

public ActionResult GetData()
{ 
    ResponseData res = new ResponseData();
    res.labels = new List<string> { "day1", "day2", "day3" , "day4"};
    res.series = new List<string> { "dummy" };
    res.data = new List<List<int>> {
        new List<int> { 10 },
        new List<int> { 110 },
        new List<int> { 120 },
        new List<int> { 130 }
    };
    return  Json(res, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you actually want output like you describe you should chenge your class to this:

```
public class ResponseData
{
    public List<string> labels { get; set; }
    public List<string> series { get; set; }
    public int[][] data { get; set; }
}
```

I generate this class with VS 2013. It now has feature to create class structure from JSON. **Edit** -> **Paste Special** -> **Pase JSON as classes**. Hope this instrument will ease your life a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You must either define `data` as a single `dataForMetric` or define `dataForMetric.value` as a single `int`.

Your problem is you're instantiating a `List` of a `List of int`.